# Exactly how slow are C, F, L, l and M of PatternLayout (log4j)?

Tags: java, performance, logging, log4j, design-patterns

It's common knowledge that `C`, `F`, `L`, `l` and `M` of PatternLayout [are slow](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html):

> WARNING Generating caller location information is extremely slow and should be avoided unless execution speed is not an issue.

Also, [this book](https://www.packtpub.com/jboss-as-5-performance-tuning/book) mentions that some applications can gain 10% speed only from changing the logging format.

But the question is, exactly how slow are these conversion characters?

Comment: @skaffman: Because then this knowledge wouldn't constitute a postable question. I've searched hard for numbers or proportions (of how slower it is) before asking but I couldn't find anything useful. I may eventually measure and post the findings. Also note that Ceki is around and usually answers log4j/slf4j questions so I was hoping for the official insight.

Comment: This are *relatively* slow, like 10x or more, usually writing to disk is much slower so if you are doing any of that, it may not make so much difference.

Comment: If you log a lot of data, it can make a real difference. But who is going to read many GB of logs? I suggest you cut down how much you write to a minimum.

Comment: @Peter, we use logs for post-mortem analysis, and since you don't know what _will_ go wrong the DEBUG logs tend to grow quite big.

Comment: I wouldn't use regular logging for DEBUG messages in production. It a much better idea to write to a journal file (ideally one which can be read programmatically) as a buffered+background task and you are far less likely to have performance issues.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I measured locally on my computer using a FileAppender. I warmed up the test nicely, measured many executions and averaged the (relatively consistent) results. The loop contained `execs++;log.info("t");`The exact numbers do not matter (because they depend on my computer) but proportions do. I used log4j-1.2.16.jar on Java 1.6.0_10 (Client VM).

It turns out that whenever any of the `C, F, L, l or M` appeared in the pattern, logging was at least 5 times slower.

[image]

Comment: For benchmarking, I'd recommend using http://code.google.com/p/caliper/. It's very easy to use and designed by the Guava guys.

Comment: @maartinus: thanks. Do you think it'd make any difference in this simple scenario?

Comment: Probably not, assuming it ran long enough and you didn't make any common mistake like letting the JIT optimize it away or using no warm up to let JIT enough time to compile it. Your figures look realistic, but it's too easy to get it wrong.

Answer (score 6):

The primary reason that these are marked as slow, is because the information they represent is retrieved by throwing an exception and analyze the stack trace of the exception.

When PatternLayout was designed, stack trace generation was a very expensive process, so this was fair warning.  Advances in JVM technology has improved on this so the process is not as expensive anymore.   Even though there is faster methods to derive the needed information today, these are - to my knowledge - not being used due to attention to backwards compatibility with earlier versions of Java.

In other words, this is not as bad as it used to be.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are not just academically interested in the answer, but are worried about the cost of logging in an actual application:

I've used them all in production applications and they have never posed a problem, primarily because logging is a relatively infrequent event. Of course, these applications were all I/O bound (not to disk/partition where the logging went) and the machines had plenty of CPU cycles to spare (but they were only PIII-1133 machines), but this holds for the vast majority of (web) applications. I'd just use them until profiling shows you logging is a bottleneck and not worry about it.